# How can I mock REST services for automated testing in Groovy?

Tags: spring, unit-testing, rest, grails, groovy

I'm working on a client code that interfaces with a remote REST service but I'm not exactly sure how to go about mocking the service for my automated tests. I've seen [this guide on how to test GORM REST](http://grails.github.io/grails-data-mapping/rest-client/manual/guide/6.%20Testing.html), which I thought I could use as reference, but it looks like it requires a Grails environment to run fine. I'm pretty sure I can incorporate Spring Test into my Groovy project but there are other things I'm not clear about. In particular, I'm not sure how to make the following lines from the link work on plain Groovy project:

```
RestTemplate rt = Book.restBuilder.restTemplate
final MockRestServiceServer mockServer = MockRestServiceServer.createServer(rt)
```

In the given guide, `Book` is a Grails domain class. in the first line above, it refers to a `restBuilder` property, and I don't know where it came from. The main concern here, I guess, is getting an instance of `RestTemplate` which I'm not very familiar with.

To be clear, I don't have to stick with this approach. Setting up `RestTemplate` looks a little complicated without the Grails environment, so if there are other tools that would allow me to mock REST services more easily in a plain Groovy project, I'd be happy to consider them.

Comment: I think this is a design issue. You should create an adapter with a well defined interface for your remote REST service, and mock that adapter instead of the service itself. Since I have not a clue of java, I cannot help more.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is an acceptable approach. I'm testing components that actually make HTTP calls so it's really a matter of routing those calls to something whose behavior I can control. You mentioned defining an adapter in the middle but when it's time for you actually implement that well defined interface, how do you test that it's actually making the right HTTP calls?

Comment: I mock out the HTTP client ofc. But I think this is even more complicated, since a REST API should send hypermedia with hyperlinks to you, and your REST client should check the semantic metadata of those hyperlinks to decide which one to follow to achieve its goal. So you don't have to test the atcual HTTP calls, just the decision making: how the client chooses between the links and how it converts links to HTTP requests. Btw. it is possible that your so called REST API is not a REST API, just an RPC which uses HTTP standards, so it does not send hypermedia to you.

Comment: Another possible solution to use end to end tests, but I guess the API does not have a demo mode for testing purposes...

Comment: Mocking the HTTP client is also another approach but sometimes it's more convenient to actually be able to dictate the response payload from another party. Sometimes you want the HTTP client to be a transparent part of the test. As for the REST API I'm testing with, I'm also the author of that so I try to make it as RESTful as possible.

Comment: I hope you are familiar with the [REST constraints](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm). There are many tutorials about REST, but most of them violate one or more constraints, so it is better to read this part of the dissertation. (It is just about 15 pages.) I suggest you to use e2e tests then. So the client, its interaction with the REST API, and the REST API itself will be tested. It is slow, but I think with it and some additional unit tests you can avoid most of the bugs. What you need is an e2e test tool for your GUI.

Comment: If it uses HTML + javascript, then probably [nightwatch.js](http://nightwatchjs.org/) or [protractor](https://github.com/angular/protractor) can do the job. Or you can try it with raw selenium tests, but then you have to handle the async nature of the AJAX calls and DOM manipulation manually.